# How should I reset a Sprite's location when it is attached to a Body?

Tags: android, multithreading, collision-detection, andengine

I am using a Pool to manage Bullets in my game. The only problem is when a Bullet is obtained from the pool having just been recycled because it was involved in a collision, although it's Body's location is reset using `Body.setTransform()` when it is initialized, the Bullet's Sprite's location (which is used to detect collisions using `Sprite.collidesWith(otherSprite)`) is not reset quick enough (as it's updated in a Physics thread). This means the newly created bullet causes a collision the instant it is created, resulting in a single bullet causing more than one collision.

I tried calling `Bullet.sprite.setPosition(0,0)` when it is initialized, but this clearly interferes, as Bullets fail to be displayed at all with that line of code in place. What should I do to prevent this problem?

Bullet Creation:

```
bullets[bulletCounter] = bulletPool.obtainPoolItem();
bullets[bulletCounter].getBody().setTransform(shipBody.getTransform().getPosition(),0);
bullets[bulletCounter].getBody().setLinearVelocity(shipBody.getLinearVelocity());
bullets[bulletCounter].activate();
```

Collision Detection:

```
for(int i = 0; i < BULLET_MAX; i++){
    if(bullets[i] != null && bullets[i].isActive()){ 
        for(int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++){
            //check for collision!
            if(bullets[i].getSprite().collidesWith(enemies.get(j).getSprite())){
                //-snip-
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to see what you're doing around the time you invoke `onHandleObtainItem` to get a bullet from the pool.

Would it not make sense to set the sprite position to some offscreen value **when** you invoke `onHandleRecycleItem`, something like:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Bullet pBullet) {
    pBullet.disable();
    pBullet.getSprite().setPosition(-1, -1);
}
```

Comment: That causes the same problem - the bullets not being visible at all. For the moment I have put in a *dreadful* hack - setting a delay of `BULLET_DELAY/2` with a TimerHandler on `bullet.activate()`. This works, but I'd like a correct solution!